# jsf poll update clears input fields

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I've been struggling with this for days.

I have a tabView from primefaces below which value is a collection of objects.

```
<p:tabView id="allChats"
        value="#{userCalcChatRoom.userChats.userListChats}" var="userChat"
        activeIndex="#{userCalcChatRoom.userChats.activeChat}" dynamic="true" cache="true"
        scrollable="true">

        <p:tab title="#{userChat.getTitle()}">

            <h:form id="chats">
                <div class="chatBottom">

                    <p:dataList id="dataListMessages"
                        value="#{userChat.chat.messages}" var="message"
                        rendered="#{not empty userChat.chat.messages}" type="none">
                        <p>
                            <span class="username"># message.user.username}: </span> <span
                                class="message">#{message.message}</span>
                        </p>
                    </p:dataList>

                </div>

                <div class="divAddNewMessage">
                    <p:inputText autocomplete="false" value="#{userChat.inputAddNewMessage}" required="true" />
                    <p:commandButton process="@form" update="@form"
                        actionListener="#{userChat.addNewMessage() }" styleClass="hidden" />
                </div>
            </h:form>

        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
```

This collection can change on the server, so I need to update this tabView every X seconds, which I can make with poll:
`<p:poll update="onlineUserList allChats" interval="2"/>`

The problem is that I have input fields on every tab, whose values are lost on every poll.

Is there a way to update the tabview and not updating the input fields?

I have tried using a simple html field, but this is also re-rendered on every poll.
I can't use IDs because the input field is inside the tabview, and I need to update the tabview, because the number of tabs can change in the server.

Thanks

Comment: but I need to update the tabview collection, and the tabview groups all the components...

Comment: should I save every input field change on the bean class?

Comment: _"should I save every input field change on the bean class?"_ it boils down to that... use ajax for it... And maybe using push instead of pull is better. You only need to update then when there IS something to update.

Comment: Updating a focused `inputField` every 2 seconds is not a good idea : the cursor is going to jump everytime.  I'd consider moving the div `divAddNewMessage` out of the `<p:tabView>`.  You should be able to track the active tab with a tabChange event thus allowing to send the new message to the active tab.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple and great solution, adding resetValues="false" to p:poll:

```
<p:poll resetValues="false" interval="3" listener="#{counterView.increment}" update="txt_count" />
```

Thanks